# Stencil Paper.loadTranslations Error

Tags: bigcommerce

When trying to run Stencil I am receiving the error below.

```
Debug: internal, implementation, error
TypeError: Uncaught error: self.assembler.getTranslations is not a function
at Paper.loadTranslations (/user/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.0/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-paper/index.js:137:20)
at /user/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.0/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-paper/index.js:62:18
at /user/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.0/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:718:13
at async.forEachOf.async.eachOf (/user/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.0/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:233:13)
at _parallel (/user/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.0/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:717:9)
at Object.async.parallel (/user/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.0/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:731:9)
at Paper.loadTheme (/user/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.0/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-paper/index.js:60:11)
at respond (/user/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.0/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/server/plugins/renderer/responses/pencil-response.js:29:15)
at /user/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.0/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/server/plugins/renderer/renderer.module.js:49:18
at /user/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.0/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/server/plugins/renderer/renderer.module.js:246:24
```

My setup is as follows:

```
MacOS 10.11.5

NVM 0.31.0

Node 4.4.0

Stencil 1.3.5
```

I have tried a fresh install of NVM and Node by first uninstalling NVM and following the guide at https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/installing-and-launching-stencil-1 end to end. This has not resolved the error and I cannot run stencil.

Has anyone else encountered this issue or have a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pull down the latest version of Stencil (just deployed in the last couple hours), you should have a fix for this. It was an issue introduced in a previous (recent) release.

```
npm install -g bigcommerce/stencil-cli
```

That should pull the update.