# Debug: internal, implementation, error , Bigcommerce Stencil error

Tags: bigcommerce

I am using bigcommerce stencil and have started working on it and run command "`stencil start`" and got this error:

> Debug: internal, implementation, error
>
> TypeError: Uncaught error:self.assembler.getTranslations is not a
>   function

Also check in local (http://localhost:3000/) got below error

> {"statusCode":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","message":"An
>   internal server error occurred"}

Can any body help me why I am getting this error?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Is there any further context to the error you are getting?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stencil Paper.loadTranslations Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38556924/stencil-paper-loadtranslations-error)