# Bigcommerce Stencil 500 error

Tags: javascript, bigcommerce

I am trying to get stencil set up on a trial store. I have a stencil theme set as default, installed node 4.4.0 as recommended, everything goes fine. Stencil start goes fine. but when I access the site through the browser I get the following error:

> Debug: internal, implementation, error 
>   TypeError: Uncaught error: self.assembler.getTranslations is not a function
>   at Paper.loadTranslations (/Users/oliverharoun/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.0/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-paper/index.js:137:20)
>       at /Users/oliverharoun/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.0/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-paper/index.js:62:18
>       at /Users/oliverharoun/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.0/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:718:13
>       at async.forEachOf.async.eachOf (/Users/oliverharoun/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.0/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:233:13)
>       at _parallel (/Users/oliverharoun/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.0/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:717:9)
>       at Object.async.parallel (/Users/oliverharoun/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.0/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:731:9)
>       at Paper.loadTheme (/Users/oliverharoun/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.0/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-paper/index.js:60:11)
>       at respond (/Users/oliverharoun/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.0/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/server/plugins/renderer/responses/pencil-response.js:29:15)
>       at /Users/oliverharoun/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.0/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/server/plugins/renderer/renderer.module.js:49:18
>       at /Users/oliverharoun/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.0/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/server/plugins/renderer/renderer.module.js:246:24

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stencil Paper.loadTranslations Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38556924/stencil-paper-loadtranslations-error)

Answer (score 0):

All is working well for me in Node 4.4.5, but I have encountered these errors in the past.  Deleting the node_modules folder and running  npm i to do a fresh reinstall usually fixes the problem for me.  If trouble persists, you may want to uninstall the global @bigcommerce/stencil-cli package and reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

If you pull down the latest version of Stencil (just deployed in the last couple hours), you should have a fix for this. It was an issue introduced in a previous (recent) release.